# Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() Hanging On Execution of Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am working with a database that I do not have much control over. I am trying to execute a stored procedure using the Database.ExecuteSqlCommand method in a C# Web API call. I have been able to successfully use this method on other stored procedures with no issue. When I try to execute this particular stored procedure, however, the application freezes. I have it in a try catch and it doesn't throw any exceptions. It will just stay in this state indefinitely. I have to go into SSMS and kill the process associated to the call. When I kill the process, the Web API continues. If I do the same EXEC command in SSMS, it works just fine returning a single row set of RETURN_VALUE = 0. I added this RETURN_VALUE = 0 manually at the end of the procedure thinking this might have been part of the issue.

The C# code is:

```
try
{
    entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC [dbo].[SPCHANGEORDER]");
    return Ok();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "SQL Server Exception");
}
```

The stored procedure does call some other stored procedures as well as some inserts, updates, and deletes. I know one of the nested stored procedures does several EXEC xp_cmdshell commands as well. I know this isn't a lot to go off of, but I hope someone can help me with a path to at least find the error. Thanks!

**EDIT**
I used SQL Server Profiler and found where it was being executed. I copy/pasted the sets into an SSMS query window, and was still successfully able to execute the stored proc.

Profiler Window

[image: Profiler Window]

SSMS Query

[image: SSMS Query]

Comment: Use profiler to capture the command, the user and the SET settings from the application, and you should be able to repro the issue in SSMS.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I followed your advice, and if I did it correctly, I was able to successfully execute the proc in SSMS even with the applicable sets. See EDIT for details.

Comment: Looks good.  In addition to ensuring you're using the same login as the app, EF will wrap the call in a Transaction by default.  So add that to your SSMS repro, or turn off the behavior with `dbContext.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;`

Comment: petty point, perhaps; but if *your server* screws up, that should be a 5xx htt code, not a 4xx http code; don't blame the user-agent for your mistakes :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I actually never got a result code, it wouldn't error out or progress at all. :-/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Adding the `dbContext.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;` line to my Web API method fixed the issue, would you be able to explain why that fixed the issue? And if you want to put it as an answer I can mark it as the such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF wraps native SQL Command calls in a transaction, by default.  Depending on what your stored procedure does, this might be the issue.  For instance if your stored procedure makes linked server calls, this could cause it to require a Distributed Transaction.

What I suspect is happening here is the transaction is causing an undetectable deadlock, since your procedure is calling xp_cmdshell.  If that external program is trying to read data written by your stored procedure, wrapping it in a transaction would cause that external program to either not see your changes, or block on your uncommitted transaction.  (Since your stored proc is using xp_cmdshell to indirectly create a second connection, SQL Server can't detect the deadlock.)

Anyway to disable the transaction try:

```
entities.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;
entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC [dbo].[SPCHANGEORDER]");
```